# Можно ли получить данные из постоянно обновляемого файла?

Tags: php, javascript, аудио, web-audio

Здравствуйте! Смотрите, есть файл, например, вот этот - "[nashe1.hostingradio.ru/ultra-128.mp3](http://nashe1.hostingradio.ru/ultra-128.mp3)". Как вы могли понять, это интернет-радио - т.е, этот файл "динамический". Так вот, можно ли как-то получить его бинарные данные? Задача состоит в том, что мне необходимо получить его данные и обработать их при помощи WebAudioAPI - получить "arraybuffer" и выполнить "decodeAudioData", а дальше уже воспроизвести этот файл. Я умею работать, со статическими аудио-файлами, а вот с такими - нет. Если попытаться получить данные этого, файла - они "загружаются" постоянно и без конечного результата, т.е - бесконечная и безрезультатная загрузка. Возможно ли реализовать получение этих данных в реальном времени на JS или на PHP? Как бы понятнее это объяснить:

1. Пользователь заходит на страницу и нажимает, допустим, кнопку
   "Play"
2. Происходит запрос к "nashe1.hostingradio.ru/ultra-128.mp3",
   сервер получает данные от этого источника и возвращает их
   назад(ajax) на страницу
3. JS получает эти данные(arraybuffer) и отправляет их в WebAudioAPI,
   который обрабатывает их(decodeAudioData), получает
   "getByteFrequencyData" и уже потом воспроизводит этот файл.

У меня всё сделано уже - получение "getByteFrequencyData" и воспроизведение файла, но это только для "завершенных" файлов - статических. Я надеюсь, что всё понятно объяснил. Буду очень признателен за ваши советы! Спасибо!

*[nashe1.hostingradio.ru/ultra-128.mp3](http://nashe1.hostingradio.ru/ultra-128.mp3) - для примера. У меня есть аудио-поток на моем сервере. 
Опишу полностью то, для чего мне это нужно - визуализации интернет-радио при помощи three.js. Всё сделано и работает, как надо. Однако только со статикой, с потоком другая история, в которой я не могу разобраться - поэтому и написал сюда от безысходности.

Comment: Вероятно в поток бесконечных данных следует вставлять какой-то разделитель, чтобы отличать границы данных. При получении данных завершать получение, если встречается этот разделитель и возобновлять снова. Или не завершать получение, а отдавать частями при встрече разделителя.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358253/php-streaming-mp3